# How to remove the app module and replace it with my own module-Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am using angular 8. When generating new application "ng new MyApp" It generate app module by default. I want to remove this app module and create my own. How can I achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: By... editing the generated code and replacing it with what you want?

Comment: but what is your intention? why dont you edit that module, you can also add more modules

Comment: Thats because of part of angular application structure. Each project of angular must have one root app module which is default created by angular CLI. so, If you need to add your own custom module you can use angular CLI command `ng generate module <module_name>` and then you can add your module to app.module.

Comment: JB Nizet:You said I have to edit the app module code and add my own.Ok I can do this bu I wonder is it possible to rename the App module"app.module.ts - app.component.html .."

Comment: GaurangDhorda: Ok. I generated my own module "ng g m  Login" . Now I want my "Login module' to be the root module.How to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can rename it. Not sre why you would want to do that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main.ts file, that is where you define which module is the root module for the project.

Here is an example of the default main.ts file:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

instead of importing the `AppModule` and using that in the `.bootstrapModule()` you would just use your generated module.